# Filter Pump: Application of Bernoulli's equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, bernoulli-equation

in my book it is written,

> "pumps are used to transfer liquid from low-pressure zones to high-pressure zones."

but if we talk in general, fluid transfers from high-pressure zones to low-pressure zones. can anyone please elaborate on the above statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A portion of liquid between a high pressure zone and a low pressure zone moves toward the low pressure zone in a way that is similar to a ball accelerating leftward when pushed to the left by a large force and to the right by a weak force.  If an external device pushes in the opposite direction, then the ball's acceleration can reverse.

Consider a wall built between the high and low pressure zones.  The wall takes on the high pressure on one side and the low pressure on the other.  This provides a net force on the wall that opposes the pressure difference.  Now consider a device that pushes harder against the pressure difference than does this wall.  This is a pump.  Rather than just holding the liquid in place, it actually pushes harder than the original pressure difference would push, thus acting opposite than would the original pressure difference.